# Passing a parameter in url Restful service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am using Jersey RESTful web services. I have below method.

```
@PUT @Path("{id}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Wine update(Wine wine) {
    return dao.update(wine);
}
```

Now how can i extract the **{id}** value here? I need the id to update wine.

Also, how can i write client for the above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following

```
@PUT @Path("{id}") 
 @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) 
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML }) 
 public Wine update(@PathParam("id") String id,Wine wine) {
     return dao.update(wine); 
 }
```